# Unsupported filetype error on adding GPG key from keyserver to keyring in one command for APT

Tags: apt

how can I add a GPG key from a keyserver to a .gpg file for APT with one command.

`sudo key-add adv --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/osquery.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 1484120AC4E9F8A1A577AEEE97A80C63C9D8B80B`

> The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/osquery.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to import the key from the server:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1484120AC4E9F8A1A577AEEE97A80C63C9D8B80B
```

Comment: This works but it saves the key into the default keyring etc/apt/trusted.gpg but I want to save it into a different one.